# HTML/CSS: How to justify multiple columns per list item

Tags: html, css

I want to have multiple justified columns (fixed number of columns) for each list item, e.g.

```
    - John      41    Singer
    - Ringo     45    Drummer
```

can this be done with html/css? Perhaps an "li" class in CSS? It needs to be list items.

Comment: You could probably just use html table....

Comment: so, do you want a list, with items which have 3 columns?

Comment: Show us some example HTML. If you have these three values per list item wrapped into an additional element each (span or something), then you should be able to get this to work using the appropriate `table-…` properties for `display`.

Comment: @Patrik Alexits , yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already been stated, but ideally this is a table of data and the right html for this should just be in a table. If you're against using a table in your html then the following solution should be fine. Update the container width for a wider layout.

Pen: https://codepen.io/joshuakelly/pen/dwBzdR

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div>John</div>
    <div>41</div>
    <div>Singer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>Ringo</div>
    <div>45</div>
    <div>Drummer</div>
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="wrapper list">
  <li class="row">
    <div>John</div>
    <div>41</div>
    <div>Singer</div>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div>Ringo</div>
    <div>45</div>
    <div>Drummer</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 300px
}

.wrapper.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row div {
  width: 33.33%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a table...

```
 <table>
  <th>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>whateverelse</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>i gues</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Then use css to set fixed width for tabble and columns..

```
 table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 200px;
 }

 th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 100px;
 }
```

You could also, if your really in need it, just wrap the table inside the list like `<ul><li><table>....</table></li></ul>` That way you could style it anyway like you want using css...

Comment: Thanks. It needs to be list items, because I want to use certain attributes/styling of a li class.

Comment: @yorgo that is a rather poor argument; which HTML elements to use to mark up your content should not depend on how you want to style it afterwards.

Comment: Btw you could wrap a table inside the li xD

Comment: @yorgo He is not wrong, this kind of data should likely be used in a table. But see my solution to display it in either a list or a set of divs.

Comment: Thanks for the help and time Hermes and @Josh, I upvoted both solutions./BR

Answer (score 1):

List-version formatted as table and hacked to look also like a list (modified version of HermesTrismegistus ;)

```css
ul.table-style {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul.table-style li:before {
  display: list-item;
  content: "";
}

ul.table-style li {
  display: table-row;
}

ul.table-style span {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="table-style">
  <li>
    <span>Name</span>
    <span>Age</span>
    <span>whateverelse</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>John</span>
    <span>45</span>
    <span>i gues</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```